# С++ sfml how to draw shapes with help mouse

Tags: c++, sfml

I want create simulation on C++. I want: when I press the mouse button, a circle should appear in the coordinates. I want use class or void or struct. And call it is class when i click on mouse (I already made this condition).

Comment: Divide your problem in subproblems: 1) keep a list of shapes in memory 2) draw these as part of your drawing loop 3) on a click event, add a new shape with the clicked position to the list. Which one are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have been working with sfml recently for me this is new. How to keep in mind? To make it as an array and when clicked, new values ​​will be added to this array and then called in the drawing cycle? Honestly, problems with everything. Although 3 is half, I do not know how to get it, but I have already set up the position.

Comment: @Botje give me 20 minuts.. Maybe i make it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to draw circle on click button at mouse position:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "WINDOW_TITLE");
    window.setFramerateLimit(50);
    std::vector<sf::Shape*> shapes;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                {
                    window.close();
                    return 0;
                }
                case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
                {
                    sf::CircleShape *shape = new sf::CircleShape(50);
                    shape->setPosition(event.mouseButton.x,event.mouseButton.y);
                    shape->setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));
                    shapes.push_back(shape);
                } 
            }
        }

        window.clear();

        for(auto it=shapes.begin();it!=shapes.end();it++)
        {
            window.draw(**it);
        }
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```